# How can I improve this Hackerrank solution to avoid timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, mergesort

Problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort/problem
My solution:

```
total_swaps = 0
def countInversions(a):
    global total_swaps
    total_swaps = 0
    mergesort(a)
    return total_swaps

def merge(arr, left, mid, right):
    global total_swaps
    buffer = arr[left:mid]
    arr_index = left
    arr1_index = 0
    arr2_index = mid
    while arr1_index < len(buffer) and arr2_index < right:
        if buffer[arr1_index] > arr[arr2_index]: 
            arr[arr_index] = arr[arr2_index]
            total_swaps += len(buffer) - arr1_index
            arr2_index += 1
        else:
            arr[arr_index] = buffer[arr1_index]
            arr1_index += 1
        arr_index += 1

    while arr1_index < len(buffer):
        arr[arr_index] = buffer[arr1_index]
        arr_index += 1
        arr1_index += 1

def mergesort(arr, left=0, right=None):
    if right is None:
        right = len(arr)
    if right - left <= 1:
        return
    mid = left + (right-left) // 2
    mergesort(arr, left, mid)
    mergesort(arr, mid, right)
    merge(arr, left, mid, right)
```

I'm failing tests 11-13. How can I make my code faster? Any other improvements are welcome too.

Comment: If posting coding platform problems, would have improved the algorithmic approach of an individual, everyone would have done that. Better try to figure it out yourself and post only those sections where you fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some small improvements you could try, but I doubt it would gain much:

- call `mergesort(a, 0, len(a))` from `countInversions()` and remove the default argument values in `mergesort` and the test on `right is None`.
- get rid of the global variable and make `mergesort()` return the inversion count, which it would compute by adding the return values of the recursive calls.
- use insertion sort on small chunks, for example `if right - left <= 5:`